# how to Import HTML 5 Css 3 animations to react native iOS Android?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am developing React Native app but since I am new to JavaScript and front end development I don't have knowledge to make animated things with JS and CSS.

But there is a website called `codepen.io` for example I would like to have custom activityindicator I have found this fine loading animation:

https://codepen.io/Rplus/pen/PWZYRM

Is it possible to use this in react native both iOS and Android.

if so how can I do it ? what path should I follow ?